# push contents of top-left cell little downward?

Tags: tables, spacing, xetex

I am going through different tutorials and Q&A, but no luck yet. I am new to Latex, and hence not aware of many packages, and not sure why some change is not coming into effect.

Currently, I have below code, I picked a template, so just adding here the relevant code to the best of my knowledge

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{14.5cm}}
 \parbox[r]{2.5cm}{\raggedleft \textsc{Aug '11 -\\ July '15}} & Application Developer \\& 
 \begin{itemize}
     \item some points
     \item some points
     \item some points
 \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
```

The text `Aug '11 - July '15` is looking little attached to the top, I am looking to give a extra top padding to it. How can I achieve this? 
Please can you let me know.
Output is

[image: Top Padding Needed]

Comment: I recommend finding some better tutorials. I think this tutorial is trying to tell you how to use LaTeX, but it doesn't even specify a document class or use the `document` environment!

Comment: @cfr Document class is `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}`

Comment: Hint: put your code in your question, rather than in the comments. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be in line with what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\setyear}[1]{{\small #1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r|X}
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\scshape}c@{}}
    Aug \setyear{2011} to \\ Jul \setyear{2015}
  \end{tabular}} & Application Developer \\[\medskipamount]
  & \textbullet~some points \\
  & \textbullet~some points \\
  & \textbullet~some points
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to find the required width of the right column using an `X`-column. The left column is set as a nested `tabular`, with the font forced as `\scshape` via the help of [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) (loaded by `tabularx`). `\smash`ing the `[t]`-aligned `tabular` allows it to extend below the baseline without affecting whatever follows in the same row.